# Redirect to SHOW action in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After creating a Person associated with a specific Account, how do I redirect back to the Account page?

The account_id is passed to the CREATE Person action via a URL parameter as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/people/new?account_id=1
```

Here is the code:

```
<h2>Account: 
    <%= Account.find_by_id(params[:account_id]).organizations.
        primary.first.name %>     
</h2>

<%= form_for @person do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :account_id, :value => params[:account_id] %><br />  
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.label :email1 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email1 %><br />
    <%= f.label :home_phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :home_phone %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Add person" %>

<% end %>

class PeopleController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @person = Person.new
    end

    def create
        @person = Person.new(params[:person])
        if @person.save
            flash[:success] = "Person added successfully"
            redirect_to account_path(params[:account_id])
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

When I submit the above form I get the following error message:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

Why is the redirect_to routing to the DESTROY action?  I want to redirect via the SHOW action.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `rake routes` and check all the generated routes to see what you missing.

Comment: The problem isn't a missing route.  He's just trying to route to `account_path(nil)`.

Answer (score 7):

`params[:account_id]` exists in the form, but when you pass it to `create` you're sending it along in the `person` hash, so you'd access it via `params[:person][:account_id]`

`params[:account_id]` is `nil`, hence the bad route.  To be honest, I'm not sure why, but `resource_path(nil)` ends up routing to `destroy` instead of `show`.  In either case, it's a broken route without an `id` parameter.

```
# so you *could* change it to:
redirect_to account_path(params[:person][:account_id])

# or simpler:
redirect_to account_path(@person.account_id)

# but what you probably *should* change it to is:
redirect_to @person.account
```

Rails will inherently understand this last option, ascertaining the path from the class of the record, and getting the `id` from `#to_param`

Comment: I added @account = Account.find_by_id(params[:account_id]) to my NEW method and the redirect_to that I had above now works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be pass this through using a `hidden_field`. Instead, use nested resources:

```
resources :account do
  resources :people
end
```

Then have an account object for the form:

```
<%= form_for [@account, @person] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This `@account` object should be set up in the action that renders the form with a line like this:

```
@acccount = Account.find(params[:account_id])
```

Then when the form is submitted you'll have `params[:account_id]` in that action without the ugly `hidden_field` hack to get it there.

Yippee!

Comment: This works, but I decided not to go with this method because the relationships between my models are more complex than this.  Thanks for your help.